# Are the words "Adam" and "Earth" etymologyically related?

Tags: etymology

Tolkein named his world Arda likely because in the European languages the name for the earth generally has an er sound and d or th sound, sometimes with a soft vowel after "eerde" "eorthe" "aard" "erda" etc.

This got me thinking about the word Adam from Hebrew which can mean man, red, but also ground, or earth in the lower case sense. It lacks an r sounds after the initial vowel, which is the most consistent element in the "earth" ancestor words. But with such a meaning connection, I wondered if there was some ancient proto-world root that might connect them and if anyone has hypothesized this before.

Adam and Earth. Anything there?

Comment: Please include the research you have done. From the Bible, Genesis 2:7 will help.

Comment: [Etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/word/earth) will give you the etymology of "earth". There are a lot of theories proposing connections between PIE and [Afroasiatic languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afroasiatic_languages): some are fringe theories unsupported by any evidence, but there may have been contact between the two and there may just possibly have been loan words related to agriculture. Such topics are better discussed on Linguistics SE though.